# the following directives don't match any configuration option: credsStore

Tags: docker, authentication, amazon-ecs

OS: Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.f
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
I'm trying to set up amazon-ecr-credential-helper and I followed the instructions from here: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) I cloned the source and compiled it manually by running

```
make docker
```

then copied the binary to `/usr/local/bin`. I added the line `"credsStore": "ecr-login"` to the docker daemon config file and when I attempt to do a

```
sudo service docker restart
```

it fails to restart. When I check the log file I see the line

```
the following directives don't match any configuration option: credsStore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up the docker engine's `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the docker cli's `$HOME/.docker/config.json`. These are two different files with different contents and syntaxes.

Remove the line from the `daemon.json` and add it to the users `config.json`. There shouldn't have been a need to stop docker to configure this.